# MySQL Create table from count

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following table

```
Event 1 | Event 2
2       | 4
0       | 8
5       | 2
```

I then query this data like the following

```
select sum(`Event 1`) as EVENT1, sum(`Event 2`) as EVENT2 from events
```

Which produces

```
EVENT1 | EVENT2
7      | 14
```

How would I modify the above query to produce the following results?

```
EVENTS
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT1
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
EVENT2
```

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows) for a hint.  You can query out a CSV list of event values and then split it into separate records.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't do this in Mysql, but with postgres you can.

Comment: This belongs as a comment.